# Snowfalke csv copy failures

Tags: copy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to load csv data into snowflake using snowflake copy. CSV column separator is pipe character (|). One of the columns in the input csv has | character in data which is escaped by backslash . The datatype in the target snowflake database is VARCHAR(n). With the addition of the escape character(\) in the data the data size exceeds the target column definition size which causes copy to fail.

Is there a way I can remove the escape character (\) from the data before loaded into the table?

copy into table_name from 's3path.csv.gz' file_format=(type = 'csv', field_optionally_enclosed_by ='"' escape_unenclosed_field = NONE empty_field_as_null = true escape ='\' field_delimter ='|' skip_header=1 NULL_IF = ('\\N', '', '\N')) ON_ERROR ='ABORT_STATEMENT' PURGE = FALSE

Sample data that causes the failure: "Data 50k | $200K      "

Comment: In your example data, you are not showing that it is escaped...you are showing that the field is optionally enclosed with quotes.  This would be handled with the FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY parameter, rather than an escape value.

Comment: Thank you @MikeWalton for response, I've escape ='\\' in the copy statement. The csv file has columns enclosed in double quotes (") so it needed to be escaped by \. In addition to that the data has | which is the field delimiter

Comment: I think you need the `FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"'` and `ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD` to be removed from your format.

Comment: Thank you @MikeWalton
I tried the below but received the same error.:

User character length limit exceeded by string "Data 50k \| $200K "

copy into table_name FROM 's3location/filename.csv.gz'
file_format=(type = 'csv' field_optionally_enclosed_by = '"' empty_field_as_null = true escape='\\' TRIM_SPACE = TRUE field_delimiter = '|' skip_header=1
             NULL_IF = ('\\\\N','','\\N')) ON_ERROR = 'ABORT_STATEMENT' PURGE = FALSE;

Comment: Without a sample file, it's hard to test out.  As a note, though, since the field is quoted, there is no need to escape the pipe value.  Can you change it on the file creation side?